# How to write the codes for add override of List<object> in java?

Tags: android

i want to have a list of CheckBox view in Android .

i was planning to try this :

```
List<CheckBox> listCB = new List<CheckBox>() ;
```

But it overrides the List Automatically said its and abstrcat

```
List<CheckBox> listCB = new List<CheckBox>() {
        @Override
        public void add(int i, CheckBox checkBox) {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean add(CheckBox checkBox) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean addAll(int i, Collection<? extends CheckBox> collection) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends CheckBox> collection) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void clear() {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean contains(Object o) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> collection) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public CheckBox get(int i) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int indexOf(Object o) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEmpty() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public Iterator<CheckBox> iterator() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int lastIndexOf(Object o) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public ListIterator<CheckBox> listIterator() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public ListIterator<CheckBox> listIterator(int i) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public CheckBox remove(int i) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean remove(Object o) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> collection) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> collection) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public CheckBox set(int i, CheckBox checkBox) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int size() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public List<CheckBox> subList(int i, int i1) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Object[] toArray() {
            return new Object[0];
        }

        @Override
        public <T> T[] toArray(T[] ts) {
            return null;
        } object in the list ?
    } ;
```

How can i override add method to obtain the desired to add my

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use **[ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)** instead of [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

Comment: whats the different ?

Comment: @Mehdi nothing. `ArrayList` *implements* `List`. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html

Answer (score 1):

Use `ArrayList` instead.

```
List<CheckBox> listCB = new ArrayList<CheckBox>() ;
```

`List` is an interface. An interface's methods don't have implementations. The implementations are in the classes which implement the interface. And one class that implements `List` is `ArrayList`. So that's why you should use `ArrayList`. You can use other classes that implement `List` as well but in this case, `ArrayList` is the best.

You get this thing telling you to override the methods is because the compiler wants you to provide the implementation of `List` in an anonymous class and all that kind of advanced stuff. You can search for that if you're interested.

Comment: yep i got it thanks . i read the oracle documentation for this i thought list is just like her sister in C#